# MongoDB Regex ignore dashes inside name

Tags: mongodb, go

i want to find Place.Name by search words eq : `"saint germain"`

i use **go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo**

**Collection Place** look like :

```golang
type (
    Place struct {
        ID      primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id"`
        Name    string             `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name"`
        ...
    }
)
```

**Database names** look likes :

```
"Saint-Germain-l'Auxerrois, Paris",
"Halles, Paris",
"Palais-Royal, Paris",
"Place-Vendôme, Paris",
"Gaillon, Paris",
"Vivienne, Paris",
"Mail, Paris",
"Bonne-Nouvelle, Paris",
"Arts-et-Métiers, Paris",
"Enfants-Rouges, Paris",
"Archives, Paris",
```

My mongodb Req :

```golang
query := "saint germain" 
XXX.Collection("places").Find(context.Background(), bson.M{"name": primitive.Regex{Pattern: ".*" + query + ".*", Options: "i"}})
```

Want results

```
"Saint-Germain-l'Auxerrois, Paris",
```

I would like to ignore "dashes", how to adjust the "regex" so that it can find "Saint-Germain-l'Auxerrois, Paris" with "saint germain" query

Comment: You just need to adjust the regex, so what is your question?

Comment: Hi sorry, how to adjust the "regex" so that it can find "Saint-Germain-l'Auxerrois, Paris" with "saint germain" query ?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex -- According to that, MongoDB uses PCRE as regex implementation. You can use that to locate info on how these work.

Comment: Do you know regex for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ignore "dashes", how to adjust the "regex" so that it can find "Saint-Germain-l'Auxerrois, Paris" with "saint germain" query

Instead of searching using [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), I would recommend to use [MongoDB Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) to run query operations that perform a text search of string content.

First, you need to create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#text-index) on the collection. Please note that a collection can only have one text search index, but an index can cover multiple fields. For example:

```
db.places.createIndex({"name": "text"})
```

In your Go code, then you can do :

```
collection := client.Database("databaseName").Collection("places")
query := bson.M{"$text": bson.M{"$search": "saint germain"}}
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), query)
```

Alternatively, if your cluster is in [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) and you are looking for a fine-grained text indexing for more advanced search functionality please see [MongoDB Atlas: Full Text Search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/full-text-search/).

Full-Text Search enables users to leverage the power of [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) for text search. For example:

```
collection := client.Database("databaseName").Collection("places")
location := "saint germain"
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
        {{"$searchBeta", bson.D{
                {"search", bson.D{
                    {"query", location},
                    {"path", "name"}},
                }},
        }},
}
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
```

The above code snippets would return similar results `name: "Saint-Germain-l'Auxerrois, Paris"`. The snippets were written using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) v1.2.x with MongoDB v4.2.x.